# XSLT to transform given query with given parms

Tags: xslt

Here is the given XML-

```
    <INPUT>
    <pSql>select * from cntwrk where moddte>= :from_date and ins_dt &lt; :to_date</parameterizedSql>
    <arguments>
    <dataType>DATETIME</dataType>
    <values>2019-07-24T00:00:01</values>
    <key>from_date</key>
    </arguments>
    <arguments>
    <dataType>DATETIME</dataType>
    <values>2019-09-23T00:00:01</values>
    <key>to_date</key>
    </arguments>
    </INPUT>
```

I need to build a xslt to have the final query has 
select * from cntwrk where  moddte>= (to_date('2019-07-24 00:00:01','yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss')) and
ins_dt < (to_date('2019-09-23 00:00:01','yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss')) 
output.

That is replace the :from_date with arguments/values after some concatenation.

Please find the XSLT that i tried, but could not get the desired output with using variables.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <xsl:transform exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
          <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
          <xsl:variable name="q_var" select="INPUT/parameterizedSql" />
          <xsl:param name="find_var" select="concat(':',INPUT/arguments/key)" />
          <xsl:param name="re_var" select="INPUT/arguments/values" />
          <xsl:template match="INPUT">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="arguments[dataType[text() = 'DATETIME']]" />
          </xsl:template>
          <xsl:template match="INPUT">
            <xsl:for-each select="//arguments">
              <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$q_var" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$find_var" />
                <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$re_var" />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:template>
          <xsl:template name="replace-string">
            <xsl:param name="text" />
            <xsl:param name="replace" />
            <xsl:param name="with" />
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$with" />
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                  <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                  <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with" />
                </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:template>
        </xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Well, obviously, if you want to replace multiple arguments you need to process them sequentially, feeding the result of each replacement to the next one. Is there a limit to the number/type of arguments you will deal with? This could be simple if it's always just the two shown in your example. If there can be more (or less), it gets more complicated.

Comment: Thanks Michael for looking in.
The number of arguments will vary (not fixed)

Comment: i am not able to pass node/element  value to variables inside for each loop.
My code only works when i pass node/element  value to variables on top.

Comment: Can the number of arguments be 0?

Comment: no, always there will be arugment(s)(at least 1).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to learn here is that **`xsl:for-each` is not a loop**. Each node in the selected node-set is processed individually. You cannot pass the result of one instance to another.

There are two possible ways to process the given string sequentially: one is a technique called *sibling recursion*, and the other is a through a *named recursive template*. The following example will demonstrate the 2nd method.

For simplicity, I will assume that each argument appears in the given string exactly once. If this assumption is not true, then you will need to call another recursive template to perform the actual replacement of the currently processed argument in the given string when calling the next iteration.

**XML (corrected)**

```
<INPUT>
    <parameterizedSql>select * from cntwrk where moddte>= :from_date and ins_dt &lt; :to_date</parameterizedSql>
    <arguments>
        <dataType>DATETIME</dataType>
        <values>2019-07-24T00:00:01</values>
        <key>from_date</key>
    </arguments>
    <arguments>
        <dataType>DATETIME</dataType>
        <values>2019-09-23T00:00:01</values>
        <key>to_date</key>
    </arguments>
</INPUT>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/INPUT">
    <OUTPUT>
        <xsl:call-template name="insert-arguments">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="parameterizedSql"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="arguments" select="arguments"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </OUTPUT>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="insert-arguments">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="arguments"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$arguments">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="insert-arguments">
                <xsl:with-param name="string">
                    <!-- insert current argument -->
                    <xsl:variable name="argument" select="$arguments[1]" />
                    <xsl:variable name="search-string" select="concat(':', $argument/key)" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $search-string)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$argument/values"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($string, $search-string)"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="arguments" select="$arguments[position() > 1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OUTPUT>select * from cntwrk where moddte&gt;= 2019-07-24T00:00:01 and ins_dt &lt; 2019-09-23T00:00:01</OUTPUT>
```

---

I don't see in your question the logic by which the inserted value needs to be wrapped in `todate()`so I skipped that part.

Comment: first of all thankyou so much!  Sure that is good teaching in XSLT. :)